# Giving Context to Fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm trying to give context using "this" to a adapter

Code is:

```
 val shoeid = arrayOf(
        "Nike air","Adidas","asics"
    )
    val progress = intArrayOf(
        10,50,60
    )

    shoeArrayList = ArrayList()

    for ( i in shoeid.indices ) {

        val shoe = UserShoes(shoeid[i], progress[i])
        shoeArrayList.add(shoe)
    }

    binding.listviewProfile.adapter = ShoeAdapter(this,shoeArrayList)
```

Data Class:

```
data class UserShoes(var shoeName: String, var usage: Int)
```

Adapter Code:

```
class ShoeAdapter(private val context: Activity,private val arrayList: ArrayList<UserShoes>): ArrayAdapter<UserShoes>(context, R.layout.list_view,arrayList) {
override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
    val inflater: LayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
    val view: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view, null)
    val shoe: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.shoeID)
    val progress: ProgressBar = view.findViewById(R.id.progressID)
    shoe.text = arrayList[position].shoeName
    progress.progress = arrayList[position].usage
    return super.getView(position, convertView, parent)
}
```

}

Type mismatch.
Required: Activity

Comment: Apparently, `binding.listviewProfile.adapter = ShoeAdapter(this,shoeArrayList)` is not a line of code in a subclass of `Activity`. You might want to expand your [mcve] to provide more details of where that code resides.

Comment: Why do you need an Activity in the `ShoeAdapter`? Neither `ArrayAdapter` nor  `LayoutInflater.from` require an `Activity`. Just make it a `Context`. My assumption is that `binding.listviewProfile.adapter = ShoeAdapter(this,shoeArrayList)` is called from a `Fragment`.

Comment: yes its called from a fragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

`class ShoeAdapter(private val context: Activity,...`

to

`class ShoeAdapter(private val context: Context,...`

and

`binding.listviewProfile.adapter = ShoeAdapter(this,shoeArrayList)`

to

`context?.run { binding.listviewProfile.adapter = ShoeAdapter(this,shoeArrayList) }`

You could also keep the Activity but the adapter doesn't need an Activity so it's best to go with the more abstract `Context`.

Comment: It worked but now I have another problem
`java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:446)
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:416)
        at com.example.speedtracks.ShoeAdapter.getView(ShoeAdapter.kt:20)`

Comment: That's a different problem. There are plenty of answers on SO already to answer that one.